# EOFError for input() only in RaspberryPi 3 CLI

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm new to python and the RaspberryPi. For my RaspberryPi 3 I created two scripts. The first (bash script) detects the push of a button and executes a python3 script when the button is pushed.

The python3 script checks some API, saves the data to a dictionary and then asks for input. When the input is equal to the data action #1 is executed and when not action #2.  Input comes from a usb barcode scanner.
Everything works perfect when I run the scripts manually either in desktop or cli mode of the RaspberryPi.

Now I wanted to autostart the bash script while starting the RaspberryPi in cli mode. I did this by adding the script to my rc.local file. This worked too, but when I press the button and the python script comes to the point where it asks for the input I directly get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*my python script*", line 36, in <module>
    scan = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I really don't know why, because this doesn't happen when I run the bash script manually and I already searched for similar questions, but the given solutions didn't worked for me or the questions didn't include something like my problem.
Thank you!

Here are my two scripts:

bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define pin as input
echo "23" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "in" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/direction

# Read value of pin
previous=$(cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value)

# Loop
while true
do
  # Read value of input
  pin=$(cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio23/value)

  # If input changes from 1 to 0
  if [ $pin -gt $previous ]
  then
    # Start the script
    python3 /home/pi/okey/get_api.py
  else
    # Sleep
    sleep 2.5
  fi

  # Current value becomes old value for the next time
  previous=$pin
done
```

python3 script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import json
from nested_lookup import nested_lookup
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD

# Set pin numbers
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

# Set pin 11, 12 & 13 as output
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)

# Set LCD & clear
lcd = Adafruit_CharLCD(rs=26, en=19, d4=13, d5=6, d6=5, d7=11, cols=16, lines=2)
lcd.clear()

# Get API JSON data from URL
lcd.message("Abfrage der\nPaketnummern...")
api = requests.get('my api')

# Serialize data into a python dictionary
data = api.json()

# Extract tracking numbers and create python list
trackingnumbers = nested_lookup('content', data)

# Get input
GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)
lcd.clear()
lcd.message("Warten auf\nEingabe...")
scan = input()
GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)

# Check if input equals a number in the list
if scan in trackingnumbers:
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message("Nummer vorhanden!")
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(2.5)
    GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
else:
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message("Nummer nicht\nvorhanden.")
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(2.5)
    GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)


# Clear LCD
lcd.clear()

# Clean GPIO resources
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Have you printed the input, to see what is actually being inputted? Could you also post what you have tried?

Comment: When I try to print the input, nothing happens. The EOFError still appears directly after pressing the button. So far I just added "try" and "except", but this "only" prevents the script from crashing so I could reboot the Pi directly without ssh.

Comment: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EOFError) says that EOF is expected if nothing is passed to your input, so it looks like you need to have a look at what should be inputted there, what is it you expect as an input there?

Comment: I'm guessing that would be the usb barcode scanner, can you post the code on how you are dealing with that?

Comment: Correct. I have no code for that. Just connected the barcode scanner via usb and it's detected as a keyboard. When I scan a barcode with it, it pastes in the code. As I said, when I start the script manually everything works. Only when I start the script automatically via my rc.local file I got this problem. And thank your already for your efforts.